# Why is static-static diffie hellman needed in Noise_IK?

Tags: encryption, diffie-hellman, noise-protocol, wireguard

**TL;DR:** Why is there a static-static diffie hellman in the Noise_IK handshake?

---

Hi,
I am currently trying to understand the WireGuard VPN protocol.
As you may know, it uses the Noise_IK handshake from the Noise Protocol Framework.

This handshake uses two ephemeral-static diffie hellman operations (es and se) to authenticate the initiator and the responder.
Then why is there a static-static (ss) diffie hellman needed?
Why is it necessary?

Thanks for your answers in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The benefit of including an `ss` computation is to improve authentication guarantees in some scenarios where ephemeral randomness may be weak. One of the goals of the [Noise framework](https://noiseprotocol.org/noise.html) is to provide resistance against [Key-Compromise Impersonation](https://www.cryptologie.net/article/372/key-compromise-impersonation-attacks-kci/) (KCI) for the relevant patterns (not all patterns provide this guarantee). The `ss` computation strengthens authentication in the scenario described here after (The context for KCI attacks is given at the end).

**Benefits of `ss`**: Consider an (*arguably strange*) scenario where the ephemeral key used by the *receiver* is compromised. A more realistic view would be a degradation of the randomness source the receiver uses. In this case, it is easy for an attacker to impersonate any sender to the receiver by simply computing the right `es`. This attack would be mitigated if neither of the long-term secrets would be compromised at this point, and that's how the `ss` computation helps.
More rationale for `ss` is discussed [here](https://github.com/noiseprotocol/noise_ss_spec/blob/master/noise_ss.md).

---

**Context on KCI attacks:**

In short, KCI is an attacker where a compromise of Alice's long-term key allows an attacker to impersonate anyone *to Alice*. So, the `es` pattern helps in that regard, assuming that Alice's ephemeral secret is not compromised and the sender's (e.g., Bob) long-term secret is not compromised. (Anyway, once the sender's long-term secret is compromised, they can be impersonated arbitrarily. That's not really an attack on the protocol).